# Proof of conditional expected value where Y is a function of $X_1, X_2, ... , X_n$

Tags: probability

This comes from a stochastic processes text, although it could possibly be found in many probability texts.

If the knowledge of $X_1, ..., X_n$ determines $Y$ completely, then the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X_1, ..., X_n$ is equal to $Y$ itself.

Proposition: If $Y$ can be written as $$Y = f(X_1, ..., X_n)$$
for some function $f$, then $$E[Y|X_1, ..., X_n] = Y$$

The book claims that the proof is very easy and hence omitted, but it is not obvious to me.

I tried working with an example, the sum of two rolls of a six sided die, where all rolls are equally likely. Then let $X_1 = 1, ..., 6, X_2 = 1, ..., 6,$ and $Y = X_1 + X_2$. So in this case $f(X_1, X_2) = X_1 + X_2 = Y$. Then $P(Y|X_1, X_2) = 1$ if $X_1 + X_2 = Y$ and 0 otherwise.

Due to the symmetry in rolling twice, I would think that the expected value would be 7, or another constant. I don't understand what it means for the expected value to be Y: isn't Y variable? Please explain what it means and the proof.

Comment: Hint: If the underlying space $X$ is discrete, what can you say about $E[Y|X_1, ..., X_n]$ for $f(X_1, \dots, X_n) = 1\{X_i = j\}$, for $i = 1, \dots, n$ and $j \in X$? What is the form of a general function $f : X^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it this way: when you know what $X_1,...,X_n$ are, what do you know about $Y$?

Yes, $Y$ is exactly $f(X_1,...,X_n)$!

What is the expectation of, say $1$?

It is $1$!

You might have also seen $E(X|X) = X$, for the reason I just stated.

So $E(Y|X_1,...,X_n) = E(f(X_1,...,X_n)|X_1,...,X_n) = f(X_1,...,X_n) = Y$.

**EDIT:**

I should have said more ...

When you enter the world of applied probability, be prepared to meet some of the most confusing mathematical notations.

For example, soon enough you will see something like: $p(y)=\sum_x p(y|x)p(x)$.

The $p$ in $p(y)$ is NOT THE SAME $p$ as the $p$ in $p(x)$!

But given how much is going on (sample space, sigma algebra, measurable functions ...), you have to appreciate it when people come up with "sloppy" notations, which can save you tons of writing (and eye fatigue) once you get the hang of it.

In your first course in probability, the equation above would be written as $P(Y=y) = \sum_x P(Y=y|X=x)P(X=x)$.

It's about the best you can get in terms of clarity, but it is still not without caveats.

$P(Y=y|X=x)$ is a function in $x$ and $y$, say $P(Y=y|X=x)={x^y e^{-x}}/{y!}$ (the Poisson distribution).

You know what you can do with functions. If you have $f(x,y)$, you can plug in numbers and you get a number out (say $f(0.5,3)$), plug in other expressions (with different variables) and you get a new function in those variables (say $g(u,v) = f(2u,3v)$).

So you could naturally also plug in random variables. You could also mix random variables and numbers, and get, say $f(X,3)$, which in the current example, has a very valid (and useful) interpretation:

For any fixed $x$, $f(x,3)$ gives you the probability that $Y=3$ when Y has Poisson distribution with parameter x. So when we use a random variable $X$ in place of $x$ as parameter, the corresponding probability is $f(X,3)$.

But then the caveat: if you try to substitute $X$ for $x$ in $P(Y=y|X=x)$, you get $P(Y=3|X=X)$. You'd be like: hmm, $X=X$ is a tataulogy, so it's like conditioned on the whole space, which is like no conditioning at all ... But they try $f(X,Y)$: you would get $P(Y=Y|X=X)$. Since $Y$ is always equal to $Y$, the probability is 1. WT%^!@#?

Don't ever do that!

As a safety measure, take it as a two stage process: first, do all your derivations in lower case letter, only after that do you subsitute random variables for lower case letters if you need to.

By far my most favorite notation is to keep all given variables (those to the right of the bar) lower case. Then whichever also appears to the left of the bar is also put in lower case.

So for your case, instead of $E[f(X_1,...,X_n)|X_1,...,X_n]$, you write $E[f(x_1,...,x_n)|x_1,...,x_n]$, which makes it obvious that it's just expectation of a fixed number! Further more, the whole thing is just another function in $x_1,...,x_n$.

As another example, instead of $E(X+Y|X)$, you write $E(x+Y|x)$, for which you have $E(x+Y|x) = E(x|x)+E(Y|x) = x+E(Y|x)$.

But no notation can beat a clear mental picture:

Imagine you have a chess board, with a value and a weight on each square. Now X is a random row number and Y is a random column number. If X is given and you are ask for expectation of Y, just the the weighted average of the row! If both are given, just read the value off of the square!

Comment: So with my example you would have $E(3|1,2) = E(f(1, 2)|1,2) = f(1,2) = 3$, correct? But how do you know it is true for any function?

Comment: I think I understand now. $f(X)$ has input variable $X$. $f(X)|X$ means $f(X)$ given that $X$ is the input variable, but $X$ is already the input variable, so that is the same as $f(X)$, correct?

Comment: @Vahan To answer your first comment: correct. See the explanation I just added (especially the mental picture part). And your second comment: you are on the right track: an expression E(foo|bar) is just a function in bar, as long as bar collects all the remaining free variables left over by foo.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed commentary! To find the expected value of the whole chess board, could you take the sum over all E(X)? (Or sum over all E(Y))

Comment: E(X) would just be the **weighted sum** of all the squares (note I said there is "a value and **a weight**" in each square, with the weight being proportional to the probability there. Sorry for the long wait! Haven't been here for a while (a little afraid of some people's ego and thirst for power here).